# Copying modules to another system

Tags: kernel, xen, porting

I configured and made a custom kernel from vanilla kernel downloaded from kernel.org. Now I ported it to another machine with simple 'vmlinuz' and 'initrd.img' copying and some grub config done. (Actually I am using Xen so grub config were also not required for me)

Now for the modules, how can I copy that? Can I copy /lib/modules/(myCustomeKernelVersion) to other system plainly?

Regarding Xen, [Ubuntu official documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/xen-create-image.8.html) for xen-create-image shows --modules option pointing to modules directory. Is it the same directory as the one mentioned above?

Note that I am using vanilla kernel and not distribution kernel. This is required, please no question on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the vanilla kernel, I would recommend building the same kernel vanilla and modules from the kernel source from the VM itself. Its may not be a good idea to use the modules compiled/available with Ubuntu as this could cause to arch / compatibility issues, panics etc. The custom kernel modules are available in /lib/modules/`uname -r` if the build has gone through properly.

Note: --modules=/path/to/modules, this option is for pointing the location of the modules within the domU, similar to "--initrd"

Comment: 1. recommendation taken, may be its better but i need to do otherwise. 2. compatibility should not be an issue as modules will be loaded only as required, and arch is same, x86. 3. --modules and --initrd point to locations in Dom0 and not DomU, in a specific folder designated for each DomU.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time in my experimentation with booting Ubuntu natively on my Android devices where I need the full modules folder, `system.map` `vmlinuz`, and `config`. You can grab the full build, source and modules and all you have to do is open a command prompt in `/lib/modules` then use

```
sudo zip -r your-custom-kernel-string.zip your-custom-kernel-string
```

Then copy the zip to the place you want hold them like your desktop or home folder and `chown` them after that. That will zip all relative files in the custom kernel modules folder.